# AWS ELB throwing 5XX but the registered instances are not throwing 5XX errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I am using `AWS ELB`. After seeing graph of ELB, there were few 5XX erros. I enabled the logs and came to know that one of the `api call` to registered instances was getting timed out as the error on ELB logs was `504`. 
I again monitored the registered instances if it is throwing any `5XX` response, but it wasn't. The nginx keep-alive timeout is set to `15s` and the timeout of ELB is `60s`. So if the request is really getting timed out than it should have timed out at instance level rather than on ELB level. Can anybody suggests what could be the possible scenario of error?

Comment: Do you have an entry in the backend instances' security group(s) that allows the ELB to connect on the configured port?

Comment: @KarenB the port is 80 which is open for all and the ELB throws that 5XX on certain api calls on every time.

Comment: nginx wouldn't log a 504, because 504 is a timeout.  It sounds like a capacity issue of some sort.  Check your instance health, and if you query a database, make sure it can return the requested data in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @KarenB I used `ngxtop` to monitor any 5XX thrown by the api instance. But there were no `5XX` error. Does `ngxtop` also doesn't log `504` response?

Answer (score 5):

The 504 is not being returned by nginx to the ELB.  The ELB is returning a 504 because it times out waiting for a response from the API instance, which also means that nginx can't return an HTTP status code on a query that it hasn't finished serving.  As this doc says, for one thing, your instance's keep-alive time should be at least the size of the ELB timeout. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504